# Bing images search in Angular

Tags: angular, bing-api

I want to implement Bing Images API in my Angular app. For now I will do it client side. But I get a 404 answer when making a `GET` request.

```
@Injectable()
export class BingService {
  private endpoint =
    "https://api.bing.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images/search";
  private token = "9dc015a3a15c45abb05f88bcea641c2d";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getImage(term: string) {
    const httpParams = new HttpParams({
      fromObject: {
        q: term,
        count: "1"
      }
    });

    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": this.token
    });
    httpHeaders.set("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", this.token);

    return this.httpClient.get(this.endpoint, {
      params: httpParams,
      headers: httpHeaders
    });
  }
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bing-image-api-d2jxzc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbing.service.ts) with the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API url is without `bing`:

```
private endpoint = "https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/images/search";
```

working [stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bing-image-api-ceb6xd?file=src/app/bing.service.ts)